# Trouble with CORS with Angular Http Request to Express REST API

Tags: angular, angularjs, express

I am currently working on an app made with Angular 2 and an API made with Express.
I'm struggling to make my Http request from Angular work as I receive CORS errors.
I have two different problems in two different environment (but I think if I understand what I miss I could correct both)

First here is how are managed CORS in Express:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

and here the post request in Angular:

```
this.http.post(Constants.SEND_MAIL, {body1, body2, body3})
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                console.log(response.json())
                return response.json()
            }
        )
```

Here is environment which cause me troubles:

### My webapp and API both run locally

When I am making a post request I get the following error: 
 `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/data' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` 
When I start the Angular app, I use a proxy.con.json file:

```
"/api/data": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "secure": false
  }
```

which I call with:

```
ng serve --port 4200 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --environment=local
```

### Angular app run locally, and Express on my development NGINX server

This time, the request is pending for a while, and then I get the following error:
 `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://exemple.com/api/data' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
But this time it only doesn't work for this particular route. All others route are working fine.

I am just beginning with Angular, so I think I may miss something important on how are handled CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the problem is with the response to [the **preflight** OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

You haven't provided a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but I'm going to assume that you are putting those headers on in the code for the endpoint for the POST request.

You need an endpoint for `options` **and** `post` and *both* need to provide CORS headers.

Throw away the code you've written to handle CORS. You've reinvented the wheel and made one that doesn't work.

Use the [`cors` module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) which provides middleware that will handle CORS for you - on preflight and final requests.

Ensure that you:

- Register the middleware before you register your endpoint (because Express tests them in order)
- Follow the [documentation for using the module with preflight requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: This works well with cors module but I don't really understand what was the matter with my old cors settings ?

Comment: See the first three paragraphs of this answer. Read the link at the top for more detail.